# Batch insert entities to DB (Quarkus, Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, vert.x, quarkus

First off: I'm not used to Quarkus or Hibernate (I'm pretty much all .net)

Problem:

My service receives a list of ~10k (Would guess thats the most common number).
This comes via a resource endpoint, and it takes +10s for it to complete, Far to long. And the service is unresponsive.

```
*Endpoint -> Service/Business -> DAO*

@Override
public void create(FooBusiness foo) {

    var statuses = new ArrayList<StatusDto>();

    for(var i = 1; i < foo.getFromList().size(); i++){

        var bar = foo.getFromList().get(i);
        statuses.add(new StatusDto(bar.x, bar.y));
    }
    statusDao.create(statuses);
}
```

The statusDao.Create() is annotated with `@Transactional`:

DAO is `@ApplicationScoped`

And this EM is:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

statusDao.Create():

```
@Transactional
public List<StatusDto> create(List<StatusDto> dto) {

    for(var i = 0; i < dto.size(); i++){

        var status = dto.get(i);
        status.setCreatedTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        entityManager.persist(status);
    }

    entityManager.flush();

    return dto;
}
```

I've been reading a lot of posts about this, and many of them suggests this property, and split the persist loop to be the same as the batch size:
[quarkus.hibernate-orm.jdbc.statement-batch-size](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#quarkus-hibernate-orm_quarkus.hibernate-orm.jdbc.statement-batch-size)

Problem is, when I add it to the application.properties i get this varning:

> Cannot resolve configuration item 'statement-batch-size'

I've spent almost a day trying to find solutions on how to speed things up, anything obvious that I've missed here?

And/or:

Can I wrap the call from the `service` to the `dao` in some sort of magical fire and forget call built into Quarkus or Vert.x?

Comment: Maybe you can try Hibernate Reactive: https://hibernate.org/reactive/.  There is also a quickstart about using it with Quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/hibernate-reactive-quickstart

Comment: I've looked into that really quick, but from my understanding this do not support H2 database yet? I'll try it out using mariadb, but there is a decision made that we use H2 as standard, and override on servers if needed. EDIT: While trying this I've been using MariaDB, and not H2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate keeps all entities that you persist in the persistence context so you will acquire more and more memory which might lead to bad performance. If you do not need these entities anymore as it seems, you can flush and clear them out in e.g. batches of 50 items.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dto.size();) {
    var status = dto.get(i);
    status.setCreatedTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
    entityManager.persist(status);
    i++;
    if ((i % 50) == 0) {
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }
}
entityManager.flush();
```

Comment: This do indeed speed up things, so I'll flag this as correct. But it's strange I cant get the property to work. Thanks!

Comment: The property is an additional configuration to also get batching on the JDBC level. It's usually best to align the batch sizes you use for best performance.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer this question definitively unless you've identified the precise cause of the poor response time. It could in principle be due to:

1. the latency associated with many requests to the database server,
2. the overhead of pinning many entity objects in memory in a Hibernate stateful session, or even
3. the cost of receiving and parsing the incoming data.

Let's assume it's not 3.

- If it's 2, then, indeed, JDBC batching would help, and you just need to figure out how to make that config property work.
- But my guess is that Christian is correct, and the problem is the accumulation of data in the persistence context. If this guess is correct then there are two possible solutions: one is to use a `StatelessSession`, which was designed with this kind of usage in mind, and the other is to use `flush()` and `clear()` as described by Christian.

I would recommend using `StatelessSession`, *unless* the problem is actually a combination of 2+3, in which case you need *both* batching, *and* persistence context management, and then in that case do what Christian suggests.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I know it's hard to pin point out the problem when not having all the facts and data.