# Hibernate JPA DB closing connection when persisting many entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a list of about 20 000 entities that are looped though and added to the EntityManager using the persists method like this:¨

```
public final void createE(e entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
}
```

So what could be wrong here? Why is the connection getting closed? Isn't Hibernate supposed to handle that and set up a new connection when needed?

Comment: What is handling the transactional scope? Persist itself is a no-op that registers the object into the EntityManager context, but it isn't inserted until the transaction commits - it is that transaction that is timing out on you. You must manage the size and connection properties so that the transaction can complete in the amount of time your driver/system is configured to allow it to stay open for.

Comment: Hmm ok but why does this loop take 1 hour when I go to remote db instead of local? Doesn't the entity manager decide itself when to actually write it to the db?

Comment: No, it doesn't, the transactional scope does. It likely isn't the loop that takes the hour, but the transaction calls (commit/flush) when the transaction commits that should cause everything you persisted to get written out to the database, using the JDBC/datasource you have configured. You will need to look at all your settings from the DB up to the app to tune them for this use case, and possibly break up your transaction into smaller chunks (or larger if you are doing so in 20k separate transactions) so they can succeed in a reasonable time and even run asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the batch size?

For example:

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 200
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html

Comment: I do have a configuration file, persistence.xml that sets the batchsize to 25.

Comment: Ok, then try enabling the logs for SQL and see what’s going on. SQL batching, or direct export and reload on the database might be another good option.

Comment: Well I have set the batching option to 50 now. In the way this is configured, I cannot get any SQL logs I'm afraid.

Comment: How is it configured, you don’t have a properties file somewhere local or a way to turn sql logging it in code?

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't Hibernate supposed to handle that and set up a new connection when needed?

Nope, that is not how transactions work. What you, as the developer can do is create and commit a transaction for every e.g. 1000 entities or whatever batch/chunk size works for you. Note that the connection closing probably happens because the network is not reliable between your computer and the server, whereas a localhost connection obviously is perfectly reliable. It takes longer because of bandwidth limitations or higher latency or maybe even simply because the database server is busy doing other IO.

Comment: I tried that, I split my list into separate lists of 1000 elements in each. This does work but still takes 1 hour to complete instead of 3 minutes as it did on localhost. Its not the actual db interaction that takes time I think, its persisting the objects in the transaction. 20 000 rows with 5 columns of integer data is not a particular heavy load and any modern db should be able to handle that with ease. Also I'm on 1 gbit up and down fiber, should be fine. The load on the db is also very low, less than 1% usage when checking the statistics.

Comment: I don't know what kind of load you mean, but writing to disk is IO bound and even if you have a 1 gbit network, that doesn't mean the database can write this fast. You would have to check a few things to understand where the bottleneck is, but usually it is disk or network IO that is causing the slowdown. Another possible issue is that you are not clearing the persistence context of your entity manager after committing. Always do `em.flush(); em.clear();` right before committing.

Comment: Yes but nothing is written when it its looping and getting persisted, its only written to db after everything is done and that operation only takes a second. Its the entitymanager that is taking time. If it was disk IO I would see it in the monitoring. Sure it can be network, but I am guessing that Azure datacenter should be reasonable fast. The code does not do any commit, flush or clear at all as I understand, I only have the code I posted. This code is around 15 years old and its spaghetti all over the place so I prefer modifying as little as possible.

Comment: If you want better performance you will probably have to change the code, and one possible source of problems is the transaction size, so you probably should do commits for every chunk. See this answer for how this could look like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619692/batch-insert-entities-to-db-quarkus-hibernate/67622297#67622297

Comment: Thanks, yes I did try that (but not with flush or clear) but the first element is as slow as the last, it doesn't change execution time at all I'm afraid. Also it would be very messy to implement as the class that uses the em does not accept a list of items, only one entity at the time. So I would have to change the interface that the class uses and all the classes that use the interface with empty methods..not ideal.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the first element is as slow", but many people improved their insert performance this way. Flushing and clearing helps to keep the persistence context in-memory small. With JDBC batching you should see better network IO utilization. If all that doesn't help you get what you need you will probably have to dig into this yourself or pay someone to do this for you.

Comment: I meant that instead of looping 20k entities, I tried looping 100 and it was just as slow.

Comment: In that case I can only imagine that this is some network IO related issue.